# select count of field by group

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a table with the following table:

```
id | score | type
 1 |     1 |  "a"
 2 |     4 |  "b"
 3 |     2 |  "b"
 4 |    53 |  "c"
 5 |     8 |  "a"
```

I need to select the count of score based on the type. So my results will be:

```
totalScore | type
         9 |  "a"
         6 |  "b"
        53 |  "c"
```

I tried both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` by neither seemed to work. The SQLs I tried:

```
SELECT * , COUNT(  `score` ) AS totalScore
FROM  `table`
GROUP BY  `type`
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT `type`, COUNT(score) as totalScore FROM `table`
```

But these don't seem to work.

Can anyone help?

Hosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work...

`SELECT sum(score) AS total FROM table GROUP BY type`

Answer (score 3):

```
select sum(score),type from table group by type
```